# Does DISTINCT rule out Nulls

Tags: sql, ssms

When using COUNT (DISTINCT fieldA), does it rule out counting NULL values that would be in fieldA

Comment: yes, by default every aggregation function ignores `NULL`s

Comment: yes but `COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(fieldA,'~~~~~~~~~'))` does not.

Comment: I though so...Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You Kind of have 2 questions between your title and your narrative.

**DISTINCT does NOT eliminate (rule out) Nulls**

However

**Aggregate Functions IGNORE Null Values**

As others have mentioned so if you want to count all NON NULL DISTINCT Values use the code you mentioned.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT columnName)
```

If you want to count all nulls as another value you can do that 1 of 2 ways.

1) Use COALESCE() to eliminate the null with a value that is not represented within your dataset.  E.g.

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(columnName,'|||||||||'))
```

2) the more certain way use conditional aggregation similar to what Gordon showed:

To show how distinct does not eliminate null values:

```
CREATE TABLE DistinctTest (Col INT)
INSERT INTO DistinctTest (Col) VALUES (NULL),(1),(2),(3),(NULL)

SELECT DISTINCT  *
FROM
    DistinctTest
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it ignores `NULL`s.  If you want to include `NULL`s, then this is a safe way:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fieldA) + MAX(CASE WHEN fieldA IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Would this be generally recommended over `select count(*) from (select distinct fieldA from t) foo`?

Comment: @GSerg . . . That depends on the database.  In SQL Server, I don't think there is an advantage to using a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
count(distinct your_column_name)
```

count only the row with a value in your_column_name different from null

```
count(*)
```

count all row in table with or without null in some column